# Defocus Node acting weird with blurred foreground. Fix?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

I'm working on an animation, and in this particular scene, I have a close up of a naval gun turret.  I wanted to focus on the middle gun, but the defocus node gives me trouble.  In the image below, I have the camera focused right and all, but the way the in-focus cannon interacts with the one in front of it looks weird.
[image: CannonsBlurred]

See how it's got that harsh line between the blur and the sharp one?  Ideally, I'd want the blurred foreground to sort of fade onto the mid-ground, which would make it look more natural.
Here are my camera settings and node setup:

[image: Blender Camera and Node Setup]

And if it helps, here it is before compositing:
[image: Gun Before Blur]